# Multi Camera Web-view

Tags: javascript, html

What is the best way to split a div container dynamically (on Button Click) into many Grids...
Im building an Ip Camera suveillance Monitor and im looking for the most efficient way to do that.

Comment: I think this should be something like jquery+css. Maybe this jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/mKuVm/4/ ) will help you to get started. But that is not the best variant.

Comment: Hi, I have to reprogram a frame based web application (with JSP $ Java Backend).

Comment: the frontend of the application is non responsive. the Camera view Grids are made with Java included in the JSP page.

Comment: is there any Framework or Plugin to make dynamic grids on Button Click ? the new frontend of the application should be HTML , Javascript and css based.